# Tags: global-warming undefined... consolidate or leave separate?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-tag

These tags are defined:
[climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate) [seasons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasons)
This one is not:
[global-warming](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming)

Should the tag have its definition filled in? Or should it be made a synonym of one of the other two tags?

I believe it should be left separate and defined **specifically** to discuss impact of changes in climate on species, and then clarify [climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate) as the working out of what the climate would be in a given condition, separate from its change over time.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the separation completely: it clarifies the differences between the two terms.

However, there are questions out there about global *cooling* and other large-scale climate changes that aren't encompassed by *warming*. I suggest we remove [global-warming](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming) and/or consolidate it with [climate-change](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) to offer a more accurate overview of the difference between the tags.

Comment: I agree. Creating a climate-change tag and making global-warming a synonym would make sense.

Comment: I like this modification.

Comment: @TimB Rather than creating a synonym for a tag that isn't defined (global warming) would it be reasonable to retag the existing ~14 questions with [tag:climate-change], define it, and delete global warming?

Comment: I've done this, although it may take a short time to take effect. [tag:climate-change] is now the tag, and [tag:global-warming] is a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the separation completely: it clarifies the differences between the two terms.

However, I suggest that "global warming" should be reserved for anthropogenic climate change and "climate change" for climate change by natural processes.

If there are sufficient questions on "global cooling" perhaps that deserves its own tag. Since "global cooling" might be involved in "ice ages" (is that a tag?) perhaps they could go there or even be dealt with under the broader "climate change" tag. As some questions about "global cooling" may be about a cooler world rather than a glaciated one.

Comment: "Climate change" in common parlance is anthropogenic. It is the term that climate scientists are trying to push instead of "global warming" which is a misnomer in some places, a hold-over from the 1990s when we thought the warming might be linear. They are complete synonyms in the debates about climate change.

Comment: @SRM The term climate change covers all forms of climate change. Climate change applies to all relevant phenomena not just anthropogenic.Yes they are synonyms, but giving each a nuanced meaning helps with clarity. Didn't think anyone thought the greenhouse effect would lead to linear change, even in the 1990s.

Comment: it was the dominant meme and the reason so many scientists push the term climate change today.   If we want to make the tag "anthropogenic-climate-change", I'd support that.

Comment: @SRM That's a good idea. I'd support a "anthropogenic climate-change" tag too.