# How can regular users enact larger changes to tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are many tags that seem synonymizable such as

- [spy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spy) and [espionage](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espionage) (espionage means "*the practice of spying*")
- [anthropology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anthropology) and [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society) ([discussion here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4427/do-we-want-the-anthropology-tag))
- [vehicles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicles) and [transporation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transporation) ([discussion here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/consolidate-tags-vehicles-and-transportation))
- [meteor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteor) and [comets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comets) ([discussion here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4346/lets-talk-about-big-space-rocks))

Because many tags are not used often / obscure, very few users possess the reputation necessary to suggest a synonym. This can be frustrating.

Additionally, meta posts may discuss renaming tags

- Changing [global-warming](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-warming) to [climate-change](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change) ([discussion here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/tags-global-warming-undefined-consolidate-or-leave-separate/4329#4329))

And tags may also come up for deletion

- [jupiter](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jupiter) ([discussion in chat a little while ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/17213); TLDR it's oddly specific and the only other planets with tags, Earth and Mars, are much more popular)
- [open-source](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) ( very obscure and the two questions with it are closed)

---

**Is there a way to contact moderators about enacting these changes once the community has reached an agreement?**
It's great that we can agree on how to improve, but frustrating that once agreement is reached, things are often left where they are.

Comment: I think you just did contact the moderators.

Comment: @PatJ I mean a more effective way - most of the discussions above were on meta and some of them included moderators, but none of them were enforced or enacted. I feel like creating a second post for every discussion asking for that change to be made is a bit much.

Comment: The thing is, do we need it to be more efficient? I agree that bad tagging is unnerving, but we have to look at the usefulness of tags first. If a tag is barely useful, changing it doesn't matter much anyway. Maybe we do need to enforce it (and probably having another mod will help) but maybe these would be enforced if there was a need to. In the meantime, how something else than Meta would make the site better?

Comment: @PatJ  as time passes, bad tags will accumulate questions, complicating the process. What may be a minor inconvenience now can become a major problem in the future - and the whole point of the SE system is "community contribution".

Comment: If these tags accumulate questions, then some users *will* be able to implement the change. So there will be a community solution when needed. Then again, I agree that moderator intervention is a good thing in this instance. I just don't think it's *necessary*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Pat said](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/how-can-regular-users-enact-larger-changes-to-tags#comment11974_4436),

> I think you just did contact the moderators.

Most of us frequent meta pretty much on a daily basis (maybe not as much on the weekends), so the odds are good that we'll see the post anyway, and follow the discussion over time, and then see when a consensus has been reached. If you *really* don't want to take your chances, though, flag the meta post about the discussion via the custom option and let us know that a consensus has been reached. Several users have done that in the past, and it lets things go smoothly.

Here's an example from a user who's done this a lot in the past:

> Seems pretty clear (currently +6/-0 and no contradicting contributions). Would a moderator be willing to effect the change?

Alternatively,

> Can we haz the synonym, please?

Either one works, really.

Comment: Thank you! Is it easier for you if I flag the existing posts discussed above for attention or does the question give enough information?

Comment: @Zxyrra On a couple of those, it doesn't seem like a consensus has really been reached. Proposing a tag synonym might be the way to go, if it's not urgent, of just waiting a bit more to see what happens and how the voting goes.

Comment: Just to clarify, flagging the *meta* post that demonstrates consensus is the preferred action here, not flagging posts on main that happen to use the tag or something.

Comment: Thanks, @Zxyrra ... your post saved me typing up something similar. I've been trying to figure out how this part of SE is supposed to work. The other SE sites I'm on I don't have near the reputation rating to be mucking with tag organization, etc., so it's never been something I've had to puzzle out before. It's really undocumented in the help how the process should proceed.

Comment: I see what you did here... :-)

Comment: @SRM No problem! See the new [sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/sandbox-for-proposed-tag-edits/4459#4459) for tags so we can organize edits a bit more